# Integrating Facebook on android and ios using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, facebook, cordova

I am using Parse for JavaScript, and is working with the ionic framework within the Intel XDK.

I am trying to incorporate social media login, where users are able to signin using facebook.

I generally know how to navigate this but my main concern is the following:
I am using facebook for javascript where it requires a URL, and when that URL is not accessible it doesn't work. Hence, on an iphone or android I cant use facebook yet.

The specific error I get is the following:

```
Warning
Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.
```

**What have I done as far?**
I went over the following guide thoroughly:
http://www.benjamin.my/how-to-set-up-facebook-connect-plugin-and-parse-com-in-ionic-phonegap/

It does mention near the end of the guide that

```
You may have to add an iOS setting or Android setting too eventually when you deploy to either platform.
```

and this is the part where I am having issues, and for a while.

I have also looked into:
http://shatter-box.com/knowledgebase/facebook-functions-for-cordova-crosswalk-phongegap/
but I am confused in how I can grab the android hashtag. I am not using eclipse, but working within the xdk.

Comment: If you don't mind adding AngularJS to your project, you could make use of this library: https://github.com/nraboy/ng-cordova-oauth

Comment: I dont mind adding angularJS to my project, but could you elaborate on how I could use this library to get facebook to work on my android and ios?